# how to take image in byte[] format from drawable folder?

Tags: android

I want to take the image from drawable folder but it should be in the byte[] format.So that i can save that byte[] into the database.I have gone through links but that is taking image from drawable folder in String or Drawable format. Any suggestion for me plz..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtain the drawable using `getResources()` method.

```
Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
```

Type cast to BitmapDrawable,

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified outputstream via [compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
byte[] buffer= out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) function from the Resources class.  It will give you an [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html).  You can then use the stream to get a raw byte array (using the read function).